# Max value from json file using D3.max function

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

```
{
  "data" : {
        "years" : {
            "YR1998" : {
                 "week" : {
                      "W1" : {   "mean": { 7.8 } },
                      "W2" : { "mean" : { 6.1 } },
                 }
           },
           "YR1999" : {
                 "week" : {
                      "W1" : { "mean" : { 5.1 } },
                      "W2" : { "mean" : { 8.1 } },
                 }
           }
        }
  }
}
```

I have the following json file above and I wish to find the max "mean" using d3.max function but cannot seem to get a result on the y axis.  The code I am using is the following,

```
var dataset;
d3.json("ili.json", function(error, data) {
     dataset = data;
};

var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { 
             return d3.max(d.years, function(e) {
                return d3.max(e.week, function(f) {
                   return d3.max(f.week, function(g) {
                     return g.mean;
                   }
                }
             }
       }]).range([height, 0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to `d3.max()` has to be an array; it doesn't work with key-value objects. Because the objects you're passing in don't have valid `length` properties, `d3.max` is treating them as if they are empty arrays, and returning an undefined value.

You can create an array out of a key-value object using the [`d3.values`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_values).  For your nested data structure, you'll have to apply it to each step of the nested max functions:

```
var y=d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 
        d3.max(d3.values(dataset), function(d) { 
         return d3.max(d3.values(d.years), function(e) {
            return d3.max(d3.values(e.week), function(f) {
               return d3.max(d3.values(f.week), function(g) {
                 return g.mean;
               }
            }
         }
   }]).range([height, 0]);
```

Comment: One more question how would i get the max mean of each YR?

Comment: You'd already be calculating the max for each year as an intermediary step with the above, you'd just need to save it within the variable.  For years, each of your years ends up being the parameter to your `function(e)`, so you could create a property of `e` to which you assign the results of the next nested function .  So that function's return statement would be something like `return e.max = d3.max(d3.values(e.week), ...` etc.